# what titles do the legitimate children of Oberyn or the legitimate children of Trystane have?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Is the title of Princess/Prince in House Martell only used by the children of the current ruler, or do the children of the ruler's siblings get the same title?

Comment: sadly unknown seeing Oberyn  only has bastards and no further information has been given on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; "We do not know"™. There is no explicit information, no precedents to draw on and the instances that do exist within the works are often contradictory.

---

The Martell family tree is not as fleshed out as other great families so it is not possible to find out an historical precedent to deduct an answer from.

However, purely speculative, there are good arguments for both cases. As Prince is a royal style used only by dynasty on the iron throne and the Martells of Sunspear, we can make a fair judgement based on practices of Targaryens (Given the absence of evidence in Martell family tree).

As per Targaryen customs, sons of Princes retain the style of Prince. For example, sons of then-Prince Maekar were all Princes. Even though Maekar's sons were not supposed to inherit the throne which was to go to the senior Branch of the family (Prince Baelor and his sons).

> Prince Maekar gave him an incredulous look. "Did the trial addle your wits, man? **Aegon is a prince of the realm**. The blood of the dragon. Princes are not made for sleeping in ditches and eating hard salt beef." He saw Dunk hesitate. "What is it you're afraid to tell me? Say what you will, ser."
> <sub>**The Hedge Knight**</sub>

and

> "No doubt Prince Maekar had some good reason for allowing his son to
> squire for a hedge knight," he said, "though I cannot imagine it
> included delivering him to a castle full of traitors plotting
> rebellion. How is that I come to find my cousin in this nest of
> adders, ser? Lord Butterbutt would have me believe that Prince Maekar
> sent you here, to sniff out this rebellion in the guise of a mystery
> knight. Is that the truth of it?"
>
> Dunk went to one knee. "No, m'lord. I mean, yes, mlord. That's what
> Egg told him. Aegon, I mean. **Prince Aegon**. So that part's true. It
> isn't what you'd call the true truth, though."
> <sub>**The Mystery Knight**</sub>

But here too, Targaryens are contradictory. While Prince Maekar's sons were styled Princes, Prince Daemon's daughters were styled lady.

> King Aegon had leapt from the saddle when the dragons were still twenty feet from the ground, shattering both legs. **Lady Baela** stayed with Moondancer all the way down. Burned and battered, the girl still found the strength to undo her saddle chains and crawl away as her dragon coiled in her final death throes. When Alfred Broome drew his sword to slay her, Martson Waters wrenched the blade from his hand. Tom Tangletongue carried her to the maester.
> <sub>**The Princess and the Queen**</sub>

This is what [GRRM has to say about](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Category/C91/P210/) contradictory nature of medieval succession laws, which by extension can also be applied to styling customs:

> "The short answer is that the laws of inheritance in the Seven
> Kingdoms are modelled on those in real medieval history... which is to
> say, they were vague, uncodified, subject to varying interpretations,
> and often contradictory."

But coming back to the Dornish, at some stage, the younger branches definitely lose their "Prince" style. For example, Ser Manfrey Martell is a cousin (We do not know if they are first cousins or further removed) to Prince Doran Martell. But he is always referred to with the style Ser as befit his rank as a Knight or Castellan as befit his office or just plain old Manfrey.

> Princess Arianne was waiting in the outer ward to greet her father,
> with half the court about her: the old blind seneschal Ricasso, **Ser
> Manfrey Martell the castellan**, young Maester Myles with his grey
> robes and silky perfumed beard, twoscore of Dornish knights in flowing
> linen of half a hundred hues.
> <sub>**AFFC - Captain of the Guard**</sub>

and

> War is happening, though Arianne, and this time Dorne will not be
> spared. "Doom and death are coming," Ellaria Sand had warned them,
> before she took her own leave from Prince Doran. "It is time for my
> little snakes to scatter, the better to survive the carnage." Ellaria
> was returning to her father's seat at Hellholt. With her went her
> daughter Loreza, who had just turned seven. Dorea remained at the
> Water Gardens, one child amongst a hundred. Obella was to be
> dispatched to Sunspear, to serve as a cupbearer to the wife of the
> **castellan, Manfrey Martell**.
> <sub>**TWOW- Arianne I**</sub>